# libgdx background image not displaying

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I have in the constructor:

```
backgroundTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Pantalla.jpg"));
```

And in the render():

```
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        myGame.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        myGame.batch.begin();
        myGame.batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0);
        stage.draw();
        myGame.batch.end();
        }
```

The full code of the class is:

```
    package states;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ChangeListener;

import mx.itesm.mty.MyGame;


public class MenuState implements Screen{
    final MyGame myGame;
    Skin skin;
    Skin skinPant;
    Stage stage;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle1;
    TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle2;
    TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle3;
    TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle4;
    TextureAtlas buttonAtlas;
    BitmapFont font;
    Texture backgroundTexture;
    Sprite backgroundSprite;

    OrthographicCamera camera;
    public MenuState(final MyGame game) {

        myGame = game;
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false,800,480);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        skin = new Skin();
        font = new BitmapFont();
        stage = new Stage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("boton.atlas"));
        skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);



        backgroundTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Pantalla.jpg"));
        backgroundSprite = new Sprite(backgroundTexture);

        textButtonStyle1 = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle1.font = font;
        textButtonStyle1.down = skin.getDrawable("Inicio");
        textButtonStyle1.up = skin.getDrawable("Inicio");
        textButtonStyle1.checked = skin.getDrawable("Inicio");
        TextButton buttonPlay = new TextButton("", textButtonStyle1);

        textButtonStyle2 = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle2.font = font;
        textButtonStyle2.down = skin.getDrawable("Instrucciones");
        textButtonStyle2.up = skin.getDrawable("Instrucciones");
        textButtonStyle2.checked = skin.getDrawable("Instrucciones");
        TextButton buttonInst = new TextButton("",textButtonStyle2);

        textButtonStyle3 = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle3.font = font;
        textButtonStyle3.down = skin.getDrawable("Informacion");
        textButtonStyle3.up = skin.getDrawable("Informacion");
        textButtonStyle3.checked = skin.getDrawable("Informacion");
        TextButton buttonInfo = new TextButton("",textButtonStyle3);

        textButtonStyle4 = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle4.font = font;
        textButtonStyle4.down = skin.getDrawable("Salir");
        textButtonStyle4.up = skin.getDrawable("Salir");
        textButtonStyle4.checked = skin.getDrawable("Salir");
        TextButton buttonSalir = new TextButton("",textButtonStyle4);

        buttonPlay.setWidth(300f);
        buttonPlay.setHeight(100f);
        buttonPlay.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - 150f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);

        buttonInst.setWidth(300f);
        buttonInst.setHeight(100f);
        buttonInst.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - 150f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - 120f);

        buttonInfo.setWidth(300f);
        buttonInfo.setHeight(100f);
        buttonInfo.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - 150f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - 240f);

        buttonSalir.setWidth(300f);
        buttonSalir.setHeight(100f);
        buttonSalir.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - 150f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - 360f);

        buttonPlay.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                myGame.setScreen(new PlayMenuState(myGame));
            }
        });
        buttonInst.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                myGame.setScreen(new PlayMenuState(myGame));
            }
        });
        buttonInfo.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                myGame.setScreen(new PlayMenuState(myGame));
            }
        });
        buttonSalir.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                myGame.setScreen(new PlayMenuState(myGame));
            }
        });
        stage.addActor(buttonPlay);
        stage.addActor(buttonInst);
        stage.addActor(buttonInfo);
        stage.addActor(buttonSalir);
    }
    @Override
    public void show() {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        myGame.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        myGame.batch.begin();
        myGame.batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0);
        stage.draw();
        myGame.batch.end();
        }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

I add several buttons and the background image. The image is in the assets folder but it juts doesn't show up.

And I had a doubt about rectangles that if there is a way to add an image to a Rectangle object the same way you set the x, y, height, width?

Comment: why do you call `myGame.batch` but not the one that you declared in `MenuState` class? BTW, don't forget to accept the answer to your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819541/androidstudio-libgdx-changelistener-not-working)

Comment: Forgot to do that! Thanks! And I'm calling `myGame` because I declared  `myGame = game`

Comment: But in that case why do you declare `SpriteBatch batch;` again in this class? Moreover I see that you have `backgroundSprite`, so why not to draw that?

Comment: I corrected the things about `myGame.batch` and I just have the `game.batch` that the class is receiving. I start the `game.batch.begin();` and then call `myGame.batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0, 800, 480);
stage.draw();` and the image is still not appearing. If I take out the `stage.draw();` and it appears

Comment: SOLUTION. If anyone has this problem, move `stage.draw();` outside of the `game.batch.begin()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Stage has it's own batch which will call begin() and end(), unless you specifically set the stage to use the same batch, the begin() and end() calls will conflict.

However you also might want to clean up your code, because you create a background sprite but not use it. I would recommend using this in stead of directly drawing the texture though (because a sprite can also have a position and other attributes which you can manipulate).

Comment: Yeah, I did found out in another forum about that but thanks anyways, I didn't quite understand why until now. So it's better to use a sprite?

Comment: Well, it makes your code more flexible and changes to the background much easier. Basically a sprite is a container for your texture which also has a position rotation, scale, size, etc.